# Create a thumbnail Python Django

Tags: python, django

```
#Model
class Article(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Name',)
   photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='news/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, 
   verbose_name='Image')

   def __str__(self):
        return self.title

   def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article', kwargs={'art_id': self.id})
```

How to make a thumbnail of the image, rename it to "* _thumb.jpg", and place it in the same directory where the file is saved?

Comment: https://medium.com/@ajitdhulam/django-framework-fc911ff95f0c

Comment: Why would I create another miniature field?

Comment: def save(self, **kwargs):

      ***

       super(Post_images, self).save()
As I understand it, I should write my code somewhere here?

Comment: the motive as mentioned is to reduce the load time.... rendering these compressed images cost you less resources than the originally uploaded.

Comment: yes, you override the save method and create the thumbnail as shown in the example

Comment: How do I then get the path to the uploaded file?

Comment: the thumbnail is a image similar to the originally uploaded and can be accessed just like how you will access the original file. For very easy understanding just think you are creating a photo_thumbnaill field in your model Article and then you copy and paste the compressed version of  photo into the phtoto_thumbnail field.... just access it like how you would access the data in photo.... ps: the folder name is based on the upload_to that you set in the model

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it. But how do I get the name of the uploaded file (not the thumbnail) in this method?

Comment: check how you can access the file attributes from this docs , 
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.name

Comment: In addition to accepting an answer, you should upvote it, since you find it good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can try this code:**

```
import sys
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from django.db import models
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Name',)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='news/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, 
    verbose_name='photo')
    thumbnails = models.ImageField(upload_to='news/thumbs/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, 
    verbose_name='thumbnails')

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        output_size = (300, 169)
        output_thumb = BytesIO()

        img = Image.open(self.photo)
        img_name = self.photo.name.split('.')[0]

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(output_thumb,format='JPEG',quality=90)

        self.thumbnails = InMemoryUploadedFile(output_thumb, 'ImageField', f"{img_name}_thumb.jpg", 'image/jpeg', sys.getsizeof(output_thumb), None)

        super(Article, self).save()
```

**Output will be like this:**

[image]

**N.B: My image file name was img_485x1000.jpg**

Comment: What if there is a period in the file name?

Comment: Or Russian symbols?

Comment: You can give a try, hopefully it will work @AeroFlow

Answer (score 0):

You need something as:

```py
from django.utils.html import format_html


class Article(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Name',)
   photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='news/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, 
   verbose_name='Image')

   def __str__(self):
        return self.title

   def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article', kwargs={'art_id': self.id})

   def thumbnail(self):
        return format_html(f'<img src="{self.photo.url}" height="50">')
   thumbnail.allow_tags = True
```